# Total JVM runs on Hadoop Cluster? JVM life cycle in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, jvm

I think this is a very basic question but to get a clear picture I have few questions can anyone please clarify?

1. How many total JVM run on Hadoop entire Cluster - Gen1 and Gen2?
2. For example, if I have 10 node cluster, What are the maximum or Min number for JVM those should run for a single node and also for entire 10 node cluster?
3. Can we control on creation on JVM at run time. Say if I have more JVM, can my data be processed fast, and can I reuse the same JVM or I need to destroy it as soon as my Job finishes.(any diagram for JVM Life Cycle?)
4. How JVM created exactly and used in Hadoop. What is a significant role of JVM in hadoop cluster(Though everything runs on JVM).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Think of JVM to be an abstract computing machine on which a java based service can run.To answer your questions:-**

1) For the sake of simplicity lets assume there is just one storage and one processing node

> > **Hadoop 1.0**
> >
> > There were total 4 services NameNode,SecondaryNameNode, DataNode, JobTracker, and TaskTracker.Each service runs on a JVM. 4 JVMs for
> >     NameNode,SecondaryNameNode, DataNode, JobTracker each.
> >
> > *A TaskTracker is a service in the cluster that accepts tasks - Map, Reduce and Shuffle operations - from a JobTracker.The TaskTracker
> >     spawns a separate JVM processes to do the actual work.*
> >
> > Assuming there is only one slot available with tasktracker to do the actual work i.e running mapper or reducer.
> >
> > Therefore, total number of JVMs = NameNode(1) + SecondaryNameNode(1) + DataNode(1) + JobTracker(1) + TaskTracker(2) =
> >     6
> >
> > **Hadoop 2.0**
> >
> > Total services- Namenode,SecondaryNameNode, Resource Manager(ResourceManager,ApplicationManager and Scheduler), Node
> >     Manager(ApplicationMaster and Container), Datanode
> >
> > 1 JVM for each service, hence:-
> >
> > Namenode(1) +SecondaryNameNode(1) + ResourceManager(1) +ApplicationManager(1) + Scheduler(1) + Node Manager(1) +ApplicationMaster(1) +Container(1) + Datanode(1) = 9
>
> >
>    *Processing is performed on container(JVM) whereas Node manager(JVM) looks after the operations.Each yarn application requires its own
>   ApplicationMaster(JVM)*

2)  *Point one describes the min number of JVMs. We can't certaintly tell the max number, as you can go on adding the storage and working nodes in your cluster         and hence the number of JVMs will go up.*

3)  *If you have more resources in your cluster, you can run multiple JVMs and that way you can more storage(datanode) and processing(nodemanager and container)    services running. Yes you can control the JVM reuse by configuring the property mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks*

4)  *Since all the services of hadoop framework run on JVMs only, JVMs are essential. You can't create JVM, operating system does that for you.You just need to     start the JVM process.*

Comment: is it mandatory that each of the hadoop services  like namenode,datanode or resource manager will have a single jvm each or is the number of jvms per hadoop service configurable ?

Comment: namenode, datanode and any other resource manager all are demon programs, these services are always running in the cluster. I dont think there will be more than one JVM for a single demon running in the cluster.

Comment: @Abhisekh...think of it this way - how can your Helloworld java program run in more than two JVMs concurrently?....Namenode and etc are java applications,hence would run in single JVMs only.